# TagCloud for Android

Tags: android, tag-cloud

I am trying to render a tagCloud from a set of given terms and weights on some Android devices. It seems that there is little support for jscript, esp. those based on jquery.

are you aware of any sort of library?
any hints are welcome.

cheers

Comment: A library that does what?  Renders tag clouds?

Comment: yes, A library that renders tag-clouds.

Comment: Did you get a solution tag-cloud or you made it at your end ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a very nice looking library with full source available [here](http://www.flexdownloads.com/#view=detail;vstr1=111)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes I know about it, but I 'rather' a CSS based solution.

Comment: Sorry, you did not specify that in your question.  The answer I provided gives options for terms and weights, as well as fonts, styles, etc. as you requested.  I don't know that there's an HTML version of what you're asking for, as you would likely need ActionScript to do complex rendering like that.